# Export custom type definition with module.exports

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create types for an existing module that has `module.exports =`. I also want to create a custom type (interface) that corresponds to the object returned by the exported function:

```
export interface Color {
  rgb: [number, number, number];
}

declare function parseColor(cstr: string): Color;
export default parseColor;
```

dtslint complains that "the source does not mention default anywhere."

I found another way to do this, namely `export = parseColor;` instead of `export default ...`.

However, that complains that `An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements`.

Is there any way to properly create a type definition for a module that uses `module.exports =` *and* export custom type definitions?

Comment: How do you plan on consuming the interface? It doesn't need to be exported for type inference to work, do you plan on explicitly declaring the type of variables/method parameters outside of the module?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger yes, that is the plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to handle situations like these.

Using your example code you can move `Color` into a `namespace` that matches the exported function's name:

```
declare namespace parseColor {
    interface Color {
        rgb: [number, number, number];
    }

}

declare function parseColor(cstr: string): parseColor.Color;

export = parseColor;
```

Then you can explicitly consume the types in external modules:

```
import * as parseColor from './color';
// OR - import parseColor = require('./color');
const color: parseColor.Color = parseColor('rgb(255,255,255)');
```

If you you will be passing the `Color` object between modules that don't need to parse, or you don't like the `parseColor.Color` syntax, then you can access the type directly:

```
import {Color} from './color';
const color: Color = ...;
```